# How to access module in child class using Aurelia DI?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, aurelia, aurelia-di

With Aurelia V1, I'm trying to call `abstract init()` from the `Parent`, where `init()` is implemented in the `Child`. `init()` uses a module, that was injected in the `Child`.
I guess I'm seeing an error because the dependency injection initialization is not completed when `Parent` calls `Child.init()`, but how do I work around that?

I've tried several ways, including Aurelia resolvers like `lazy` and `parent`.

```js
export abstract class Parent {
  protected constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  protected abstract init();
}
```

```js
@autoinject()
export class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(
    private i18n: I18N, // how to import this?
  ) {
    super();
  }

  protected init() {
    this.i18n.tr() // throws error
  }
}
```

`Message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tr')`

### Possible solutions

#### 1. Use a different structure so that Aurelia lifecycle methods get called

In this case, I don't really wan't to do that, because these are just plain utility classes (validators).

#### 2. Call init from Child class instead of Parent

```js
export abstract class Parent {
  protected constructor() {}

  protected abstract init();
}
```

```js
@autoinject()
export class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(
    private i18n: I18N,
  ) {
    super();
    this.init();
  }

  protected init() {
    this.i18n.tr() // works 
  }
}
```

Of course I could just call init from `Child`, which would work. Still, I try to understand if there's a better solution or if there's an "the Aurelian way".

#### 3. Add i18n to Parent constructor and pass it with super()

```js
export abstract class Parent {
  protected constructor(protected i18n: I18N) {}

  protected abstract init();
}
```

```js
@autoinject()
export class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(
   i18n: I18N,
  ) {
    super(i18n);
  }

  protected init() {
    this.i18n.tr() // works 
  }
}
```

Again, this would work, but I don't want to change all existing child classes. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Container.instance.get()` approach in child method.

```
import {Container} from 'aurelia-framework'

@autoinject()
export class Child extends Parent {
  private i18n: I18N;


  protected init() {
     this.i18n = Container.instance.get(I18N);

      this.i18n.tr('KEY') 
   }
 }
```

Comment: That won't work if `Parent` calls `init()` from its constructor as shown in my initial example. 

`Error invoking I18N. Check the inner error for details. (Message: Maximum call stack size exceeded)`